# Horizontal div for thumbnails

Tags: css, html-lists, overflow

I want to do an horizontal div that displays de several thumbnails with a button previous and next.
These buttons will serve to scroll the div.

Someone can explain me how to do that?

I want the thumbnail to be shown as in the picture:
[image]

My code for thumbnails:

```css
.portfolio-arrows {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  right: 0;
}
.portfolio-arrows .left, .portfolio-arrows .right {
  width: 35px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.portfolio-arrows .left i, .portfolio-arrows .right i {
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: grey;
}

.portfolio-thumbs {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}
.portfolio-thumbs .thumbs-list {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.4s;
  transition: transform 0.4s;
}
.portfolio-thumbs .thumbs-list ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
.portfolio-thumbs .thumbs-list ul li {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="portfolio-arrows">
  <div class="left" data-slide="prev">
    <i class="icon-left-open icon-bottom"></i>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </div>
  <div class="right" data-slide="next">
    <i class="icon-right-open icon-bottom"></i>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </div>

</div>
<div class="portfolio-thumbs">
      <div class="row no-margin">
        <div class="thumbs-list">
          <ul>
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
            <li>4</li>
            <li>5</li>
            <li>6</li>
            <li>7</li>
            <li>8</li>
            <li>9</li>
            <li>10</li>
            <li>11</li>
            <li>12</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Thank's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.portfolio-arrows {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  right: 0;
}
.portfolio-arrows .left, .portfolio-arrows .right {
  width: 35px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.portfolio-arrows .left i, .portfolio-arrows .right i {
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: grey;
}

.portfolio-thumbs {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 200px;
}
.portfolio-thumbs .thumbs-list {
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.4s;
  transition: transform 0.4s;
  list-style: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 0;
}
.portfolio-thumbs .thumbs-list li {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="portfolio-arrows">
  <div class="left" data-slide="prev">
    <i class="icon-left-open icon-bottom"></i>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </div>
  <div class="right" data-slide="next">
    <i class="icon-right-open icon-bottom"></i>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </div>

</div>
<div class="portfolio-thumbs">
      <div class="row no-margin">
          <ul class="thumbs-list">
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
            <li>4</li>
            <li>5</li>
            <li>6</li>
            <li>7</li>
            <li>8</li>
            <li>9</li>
            <li>10</li>
            <li>11</li>
            <li>12</li>
          </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank's. How can i give action to buttons scroll 200px to right and left? @Trix

Comment: You are welcome. That could be done using some JavaScript. That would be nice to ask another question for the JavaScript part

Answer (score 1):

user3242861

I have *a proposal* for you.

If you doing for do it faster,
**you can use [slick.js](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) for solve it.**
this is library for make simple slideshow.

it easy to use !!

**Example** :

```js
$('#slide').slick({
  infinite: true,
  slidesToShow: 5,
  slidesToScroll: 5
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #ccc;
}

.box {
  background: #fafafa;
  text-align:center;
  margin:10px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.js"></script>

<div id="slide">
  <div class="box id-1"><h1>S1</h1></div>
  <div class="box id-2"><h1>S2</h1></div>
  <div class="box id-3"><h1>S3</h1></div>
  <div class="box id-4"><h1>S4</h1></div>
  <div class="box id-5"><h1>S5</h1></div>
  <div class="box id-6"><h1>S6</h1></div>
  <div class="box id-7"><h1>S7</h1></div>
  <div class="box id-8"><h1>S8</h1></div>
  <div class="box id-9"><h1>S9</h1></div>
  <div class="box id-10"><h1>S10</h1></div>
</div>
```

---

But you doing for practice your skill,

you should use Javascript : ) and search "tutorial image slide js"

**Fighting !!**